# using sum and count inside case sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, case

I want to do count for each row from table but I get this error:

> Can not perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

```
   SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) AS ID, 
           MONTH(p.datep) AS nMonth, 
           DATENAME(mm, p.dateP) AS month, 
           YEAR(p.dateP) AS year, c.EId, e.SId,
           e.nE, s.libelle,
           SUM(p.a) AS a, 
           SUM(p.a - p.b) AS c, 
           SUM(p.b) AS b, 
           SUM(p.dureePM + p.dureeAM) AS dX,
           SUM(CASE WHEN p.dureePm != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbrPm, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN p.dureeAm != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbrAm, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN p.nbX > 2 THEN  SUM(p.nbX-2)  ELSE 0 END) AS nbrXSupp, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN p.nbY > 2 THEN  SUM(p.nbY-2)  ELSE 0 END) AS nbrYSupp

FROM       dbo.table AS p 
INNER JOIN
           dbo.tableC AS c ON p.cId = c.CId 
INNER JOIN
           dbo.tableE AS e ON c.EId = e.EId 
INNER JOIN
            dbo.tableS AS s ON e.SId = s.SId

GROUP BY MONTH(p.dateP), DATENAME(mm, p.dateP), YEAR(p.dateP), 
          c.EId, e.SId, e.nE, s.libelle
```

Comment: What DB do you working with? on Oracle an SUM ( expr ) give you an information about the content of the complete tabe, and not for rows

Comment: Thanks for answering, i'm working with sqlServer

Comment: i need the sum for the content of each row

Comment: show us your table & expected result. It will help us to give you perfect solution.

Comment: sum for rows is: select x+y as result from table. If you like to count something in each row, you need subselects there

Comment: @Magnolia can u give some sample data with expected result so we can help

Comment: @MahediSabuj and Ragesh ; please check now .

Comment: @Gambotic , even with subselects it give me the same error

Comment: Why do you need a SUM at all? Your expected result does not look like it requires aggregation. Also, aggregation has to be on some basis 
(generally provided using GROUP BY), else it definitely SUM all rows. Just remove the sum , doesn't it solves your problem?

Comment: And where are you putting COUNT to count rows, that is resulting in this error?

Comment: @AkankshaSingh : please check now

Comment: There you go. Now the error makes more sense. SQL server does not support an aggregate function in an aggregate function. Here your are using a COUNT outside SUM. Have a look at the answer I'll post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment, SQl server doesn't support aggregate function inside another. you can achieve you purpose by breaking your query in two steps. I have kept your query in a cte and further queried it to get count on the columns you needed.

```
 with cte as
(
 SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) AS ID, 
           MONTH(p.datep) AS nMonth, 
           DATENAME(mm, p.dateP) AS month, 
           YEAR(p.dateP) AS year, c.EId, e.SId,
           e.nE, s.libelle,
           SUM(p.a) AS a, 
           SUM(p.a - p.b) AS c, 
           SUM(p.b) AS b, 
           SUM(p.dureePM + p.dureeAM) AS dX,
           SUM(CASE WHEN p.dureePm != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbrPm, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN p.dureeAm != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbrAm, 
           CASE WHEN p.nbX > 2 THEN  SUM(p.nbX-2)  ELSE 0 END AS nbrXSupp, --removed the COUNT
           CASE WHEN p.nbY > 2 THEN  SUM(p.nbY-2)  ELSE 0 END AS nbrYSupp

FROM       dbo.table AS p 
INNER JOIN
           dbo.tableC AS c ON p.cId = c.CId 
INNER JOIN
           dbo.tableE AS e ON c.EId = e.EId 
INNER JOIN
            dbo.tableS AS s ON e.SId = s.SId

GROUP BY MONTH(p.dateP), DATENAME(mm, p.dateP), YEAR(p.dateP), 
          c.EId, e.SId, e.nE, s.libelle
)
select cte.*,count(nbrXSupp) as Cn_nbrXSupp,count(nbrYSupp) as Cn_nbrYSupp
from cte
group by nMonth,month,year,EId,SId, nE,libelle
```

Hope it helps. Obviously I haven't run and tested it.If there are any column binding issues in the query, please sort them out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a CTE. 
Hope this help

CREATE TABLE ##tableA (id INT, x INT, y INT)
INSERT INTO  ##tableA  VALUES
(1, 5, 3),
(2, 7, 2),
(3, 2, 5)

;WITH SUMS AS(
SELECT  id,
 CASE WHEN x> 2 THEN  (x-2)  ELSE 0 END AS number1, 
 CASE WHEN y > 2 THEN (y-2)  ELSE 0 END AS number2

FROM       ##tableA
)

SELECT
*
FROM SUMS

Comment: please check now . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SUM(T1Count.TotalRec) T1Counts, SUM(T2Count.TotalRec) T2Counts 
From Table1 T01 
Outer Apply (Select COUNT(T01_Id) TotalRec From Table1 T1 Where T1.T01_Id=T01.T01_Id And T01_FieldToCheck > 1) T1Count
Outer Apply (Select COUNT(T01_Id) TotalRec From Table1 T1 Where T1.T01_Id=T01.T01_Id And T01_FieldToCheck =< 1) T2Count
```

I think this would help you a little to sort out your problem. This way you can have different conditional summary on your data.

get back if any problem in the same.

Comment: Thank you ,  but the query is mush more complicated than what i posted , please re-checked now

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
SELECT id,
CASE WHEN min(x)> 2  THEN  (min(x)-2) ELSE 0  END AS number1, 
CASE WHEN min(y) > 2 THEN (min(y)-2)  ELSE 0 END AS number2
FROM tableA
group by id
```

Output :-

```
id  number1 number2
 1     3    1
 2     5    0
 3     0    3
```